# Store Amazon Athena Query Results into new Table

Tags: amazon-athena, pyathena

I need to store Amazon Athena query results into New Amazon Athena Table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently they have added [Create Table as CTAS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-console.html#ctas-create-from-query) support to Athena.

Answer (score 6):

**Updates:**

Athena now supports Create Table as Select Queries (CTAS).  Examples are available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-examples.html).

They have implemented several nice feautes, namely the ability to apply compression to outputs (GZIP, SNAPPY) and supply output format.

Comment: One thing to note is that you need to be sure you remove old data when refreshing these queries